# Future perfect progressive tense question

Tags: grammar

I don't understand the grammar in this sentence: "By this time next summer, you will have completed your studies and found a job."
I understand that the first half is future perfect progressive but why is the verb "found"in the second half in past tense and "not will have found"?

Thanks

Comment: There is no progressive involved here: it is simply the future perfect. The future perfect progressive is ‘you will have been completing’ (as in, “Yeah, I’ve been completing my thesis for quite a while now. By next year, I will have been completing it for five years”).

Answer (score 3):

It is understood that the sentence reads

> By this time next summer, you will have completed your studies and [you will have] found a job.

It is shortened because of this implicit construction.

Answer (score 2):

Because "you will have" works for both "studied" and "found". The sentence will sound strange and unnecessarily long if you write "will have" twice.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that "will have" is transitive across "found a job"